# when i click link how to change selected color in image in css using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

When I click link, how to change selected color in image in CSS using JavaScript?
How do I use JavaScript in below code?

```css
    .review {
      padding-left: 55px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .icon1 {
      display: inline-block;
      background: url('../userimage/icon.jpg') no-repeat -32px -40px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 14px;
      padding-left: 6px;
    }
    .icon2 {
      display: inline-block;
      background: url('../userimage/icon.jpg') no-repeat -32px -66px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 14px;
      padding-left: 6px;
    }
    .icon1:hover {
      background: url('../userimage/icon.jpg') no-repeat -13px -40px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .icon2:hover {
      background: url('../userimage/icon.jpg') no-repeat -13px -66px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .icon {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #848484;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<p class="review">
  Was this review helpful?
  <a class="icon" id="jp">
    <span class="icon1"></span>
    Yes
  </a>
  <a class="icon"><span class="icon2"></span>No</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: when i click button how to selected color come to botton and when i again click button no clolor come to button

Comment: how to style a selected button/link with css or javascript

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Change color of links javascript CSS

Comment: how to change the color of link when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Ok `:visited` works from the browser history, and I think you want to change the color of the clicked link only. I put some jQuery together

```
$('a').click(function(){
 if ( $(this).is(":visited"))
     $(this).removeClass("visited");
 else
     $(this).addClass("visited");
 });
```

and the CSS

```
    a{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

a.visited{
color:#205081;
}
```

Comment: how to use both like addclass and remove class in single function.give example

Comment: because it will only work if class already exist on that element

Comment: if it is possible to change image color in above case when i use